# Spring boot spark application

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to implement a spark application. I build an uber jar, and use spark-submit to execute the application. But I got the following exception:

> 18/06/05 15:32:37 ERROR SpringApplication: Application run failed
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gsonBuilder' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.google.gson.GsonBuilder]: Factory method
>   'gsonBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.BootstrapMethod
>
> Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
>       .....

The exception is still there even if I put the following dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.5</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>           
</dependency>
```

How can I resolve this dependency issue?

Comment: Check your mvn dependency:tree to verify that you are not getting multiple gson libs.

Comment: do you call `setLenient`? If so, you might want to check the version actually used in your build, spring-boot's dependency management sometimes overrides dependency versions and maybe puts one that doesn't have this method yet/anymore. And if you don't call that method, it might be autoconfiguration code of boot in which case you may have luck not putting a `<version>` so boot gets the version it wants. Sidenote, boot uses jackson all over the place, maybe you can also use that instead of gson

Comment: I checked installed spark jar folder, and found a gson-2.2.4.jar which doesn't have setLenient method. It seems that this jar file is used for running application although I build a uber jar.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {GsonAutoConfiguration.class})` to disable gson autoconfiguration.

Comment: This solved the problem for me! I've checked my project dependency tree and found out that `Gson` is only required by `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.6.5` which is a dependency of `Spark` and not `Spring`. So I was looking for something to avoid `Spring` messing ups!